# Turn luacov/luacov.cpp into a Lua module

Tags: c++, lua

I am new Lua user. No experience with C++. I need to have test code coverage functionality my tests in Lua so after googling I found this site:
https://github.com/nmcveity/lcovtools
Nice but the author says:

`"Turn luacov/luacov.cpp into a Lua module"`

and I stopped here. No experience what tool to use to do this.
I am Windows 8.1 user; Lua ver 5.1.4 .
Can somebody deliver me a ready to use solution for my problem (eg which compilator with all magic options to have ready to use Lua module)
Thanks in advance.

Rafal

Answer (score 0):

compile it as DLL named lcovtools.dll. You can use any compiler you want but i recommend using Visual Studio. Create a new DLL Project. Delete all files and just add luacov.cpp

You can follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms235636.aspx on how to setup the project

http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8 here is a free version of Visual Studio.